# R - How to use connection instead of file?

Tags: r, file, text, connection

Is there a generic way to supply a function which expects a text file as input with a string instead?

I want to convert 56000+ svg 'files' into a raster/grid format (bitmap, png or similar)

But the svg files are not stored as files, but rather as strings in a data frame

I thought I could use textConnection but I'm not having any luck:

```
> pseudo_file <- textConnection(data[1,"svg"])
> bitmap <- rsvg(pseudo_file)
Error: is.raw(svg) is not TRUE
```

Comment: What is in `data[1, "svg"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works for me. Make sure that the strings are recognized as correct URL's for R: the `\` should be replaced by `\\` or `/`.

```
library(rsvg)
myfiles <- c("example.svg" , "example.svg")
for(i in myfiles) {
  test <- rsvg(i)
}
test
```

If the SVG is a string, you can use `charToRaw` to convert SVG strings into raw data.